# Self-Sizing UITableViewCell iOS 8

Tags: objective-c, ios8

I am currently trying to implement the self-sizing table view cells into my iOS 8 app. Previously, I used a static table view to display my content, but in order to use the self-sizing feature, I had to switch it to dynamic/prototype. I have 8 different prototype cells, each with different identifiers. I am looking to self-size SOME of my prototype cells, but not others. Is this doable?

Comment: Others who aren't self-sized have proper constraints for auto-layout?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. All the cells will be self-sizing, and that's the way it should be. Apple expects new apps to use dynamic text for instance, and if the user chooses a large text size, you would want your cells to expand. Why do you want some of the cells to not be self-sizing?

Comment: Well, I want some cells to have a limit on how much can appear. Like, a character limit for a specific cell.

Comment: Take a look at this project : https://github.com/smileyborg/TableViewCellWithAutoLayoutiOS8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, if the cell should be self-sizing:

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = (your default row height)
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

In `heightForRowAtIndexPath`, if the cell should be self-sizing:

```
return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Otherwise, if you want a static, non-resizing cell, in `heightForRowAtIndexPath`,

```
return (your default row height)
```